# Horizontally-scrolling flexbox container does not respect padding

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow, padding

I'm trying to set up a page layout with flexbox such as the one illustrated here: https://jsfiddle.net/axedre/o6xw7pfg/, but I can't figure out why the `.main` div (as per the example) does not add padding to the right of the `.content` div when the latter grows beyond allotted space.
You can see what I mean by un-commenting line 30 in the SCSS section of the fiddle and scrolling the `.main` div all the way to the right.
Even if I remove the `padding` property from `.main` and add the same values to a `margin` property on `.content` I can't get the desired result, which is to have a space on the right-hand side of `.content` even when one scrolls to the right end of `.main`.
Any help is greatly appreciated, cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple fix for that, where to make `.content` display as `inline-block` and use `margin` instead of `padding`

This works on Firefox, Edge, IE11, but not on Chrome. Luckily though, by simply add a padding, e.g. `padding-right: 0.1px;`, to `.main` fixes that.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/597tn4oo/)

Stack snippet

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.top {
  border: 2px solid lime;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
.top .firstcol {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
}
.top .firstcol .header {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
.top .firstcol .main {
  border: 1px solid navy;
  flex: 1;
  padding-right: 0.1px;                   /*  fix for Chrome  */
  overflow: auto;
}
.top .firstcol .main .content {
  display: inline-block;                  /*  added  */
  margin: 1rem 2rem;                      /*  added here as margin instead  */
  border: 2px solid maroon;
  width: 1000px;
}

.top .firstcol .footer {
  border: 1px solid magenta;
}
.top .secondcol {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.top .secondcol .othercontent {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div class="firstcol">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="content">content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <code>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</code>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="secondcol">
    <div class="othercontent">fixed</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Another solution would be to add an extra wrapper, displayed as `inline-block`, which might be more *hack free* than the previous.

[Updated fiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/awfgt22n/)

Stack snippet 2

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.top {
  border: 2px solid lime;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
.top .firstcol {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
}
.top .firstcol .header {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
.top .firstcol .main {
  border: 1px solid navy;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
.top .firstcol .main .fix-right-margin {
  display: inline-block;
}
.top .firstcol .main .content {
  border: 2px solid maroon;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 1rem 2rem;
}

.top .firstcol .footer {
  border: 1px solid magenta;
}
.top .secondcol {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.top .secondcol .othercontent {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div class="firstcol">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="fix-right-margin">
        <div class="content">content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <code>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</code>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="secondcol">
    <div class="othercontent">fixed</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, just setting `display: inline-block` to `.content` and leaving everything else as-is (padding on `.main` and no margin on `.content`) fixes the problem and is hack-free! See updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/axedre/597tn4oo/3/, great idea! Thanks!

Comment: P.S. Works on Chrome 64, by the way!

Comment: @AndreaAloi Yes, but that doesn't work on Firefox and Edge.

Comment: Right, will run a few more tests but browser-compatibility is not my main concern at the moment! :)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out thanks to [this article](https://www.brunildo.org/test/overscrollback.html), and jotted down this css class that does the trick:

```
.ensure-padding {
    position: relative;
}

.ensure-padding::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 1px;
}
```

Now one simply needs to add the `.ensure-padding` class to leave some space to the right of an element when it overflows its container, as shown [here](https://jsfiddle.net/axedre/o6xw7pfg/3/). The only downside is that the value for the `width` property on the `::after` pseudo-class has to equal the value of the `padding-right` property on the `.main` container, so when the the latter changes the `.ensure-padding` property has to be updated accordingly.